# How to handle API failures in an iOS 14 Widget

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

I am building a widget which displays a simple list of bookings obtained from an API. I have set up the API call from the `getTimeline` method as shown in plenty of tutorials however none of them cover what to do when something goes wrong with the call.

```
func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    
    NetworkManager().getTimelineEntries { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let entries):
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
            completion(timeline)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

We're using login credentials which are stored in the keychain and I would like to show a static view if the user is not logged in (credentials are null). I'd also like to show a static view if the user is logged in but the request fails or returns zero entries.

As the API call is currently carried out in the `getTimeline` method I'm unsure of the best way to handle these cases. I could return a single timeline entry which is configured to display a custom message but this doesn't seem like the best approach and there must be a better way to handle this. For non-logged in users it seems wrong to attempt the API call when we know it's going to fail so is there a way to handle this outside the timeline provider?

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way is to return a `Timeline` with a single empty-state/placeholder/"whoops, something went wrong!" `Entry` and request a new timeline after 15 mins (you could request a refresh after a shorter interval, e.g. 5 mins, but [Apple may ignore depending on your refresh budget, users' device usage & widget location](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date)):

```swift
func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    
    NetworkManager().getTimelineEntries { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let entries):
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
            completion(timeline)
        case .failure(let error):
            let currentDate = Date()
            let entries = [Entry(date: currentDate, yourData: nil)] //Could include error here, to display on widget UI
            let policy = .after(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 15, to: currentDate) ?? currentDate.addingTimeInterval(900))
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: policy)
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically the solution I came up with myself yeah, thank you though. My `TimelineEntry` struct has an optional data and an optional error param so I have 3 conditions, valid entry, error entry or no data (meaning no bookings on our platform). I have then set the refresh policy dependant on the type of error, for example if the user is logged out the policy is `.never` as the timelines get reloaded when the user next logs in anyway.

It seems crazy to me that there doesn't seem to be a mechanism for handling errors built into the architecture of widgets. Thanks Apple.

Comment: You're telling me, @Leon, what's especially annoying is trying to load several different images asynchronously, outside of the Widget view(model)s - you basically have to do all your prefetching in your `NetworkManager()` code after hitting your api the first time to get the asset urls... Not to mention layout bugs/restrictions in `WidgetKit`...

So many wacky choices from Apple when it comes to WidgetKit. I've had trouble getting Firebase to work inside Widgets, so I've had to rely on hacks in my App to get the info that I desire for Analytics/Usage.